# How to use .csslintrc in Atom's CSSLint to ignore rules?

Tags: atom-editor, csslint, linter

I'm using [Linter](https://github.com/steelbrain/linter) with [Linter-CSSlint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-csslint) in Atom (windows) and I want to prevent some warnings globally (like "ids").

In CSSlint's readme says that it supports `.csslintrc` but I can't find info of *where* should I put this `.csslintrc` file.

I saw a `.csslintrc` file inside:

```
.atom
  \packages
    \linter-csslint
      \spec
        \fixtures 
          \project
```

with this inside: `--errors=empty-rules`

But adding there some rules there doesn't do anything. Rules like:

```
--errors=empty-rules
{
    "ids": false,
     "box-model": false,
 }
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `.csslintrc` file into the root directory of your project with the setup below:

```
{
    "adjoining-classes": false,
    "box-model": false,
    "box-sizing": false,
    "compatible-vendor-prefixes": false,
    "floats": false,
    "font-sizes": false,
    "gradients": false,
    "important": false,
    "known-properties": false,
    "outline-none": false,
    "overqualified-elements": false,
    "qualified-headings": false,
    "regex-selectors": false,
    "shorthand": false,
    "text-indent": true,
    "unique-headings": false,
    "universal-selector": false,
    "unqualified-attributes": true
}
```

That's it!

For more information, consult the [CSSLint documentation](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

After wasting a lot of time trying to solve this and other configuration problems, I found that the solution is to switch to [stylelint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-stylelint).

Comment: Thank! stylelint take a little bit to config initially but it really work. On the other hand I'm not sure if I can accept this as the correct answer because technically isn't an answer for the question per sé...